# How do I deal with an automatic reboot following a cydia app install

Tags: cydia, reboot

The tethered RedSnOw jailbreak for 5.1 worked like a charm.  I ran into a problem when I installed winterboard however.  Following the automatic reboot, I couldn't get my iPhone into DFU mode to use the "just reboot" function.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well, good news for you. As from a few weeks ago, you are able to jailbreak your iOS 5.1 **untethered**, which eliminates the fact you've to "just-boot" the iPhone very time.

In order to do so, [Jailbreak nation](http://www.jailbreaknation.com/jailbreak-5.1.1-untethered-ios-with-absinthe-2.0-iphone-4s43gs-ipad-321-ipod-touch-4g3g) has published a very detailed and good tutorial on how to jailbreak your iPhone. I suggest you preform a untetheredjailbreak and try again. If things are still not working, please give some feedback with your errors so we can help you further.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be anything different about getting your device into DFU mode after a Cydia-initiated reboot compared to a normal reboot.

Generally if people have trouble getting into DFU mode, the causes can include: not having the latest version of iTunes installed, using a USB hub/a bad USB cable/a bad USB port, holding the buttons for the wrong amount of time (or pressing them too hard sometimes), or having faulty buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Restore your iphone/ipod to 5.1 then jailbreak it again.

Comment: You shouldn't have to restore and jailbreak again - you should be able to boot tethered using redsn0w. If redsn0w isn't working, there is probably a way to make it work.